# Treat string like it is a piece of code in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, I would like to read a CSV file, get all column names and dynamically pass them to a for loop, to select items on each row, for each column name. To do so, I have the following script:

```
$CSV_Employees = Import-Csv "C:\Users\L_L\Desktop\Employees_v2.csv"

$output_array = @()
foreach($HEADER in $CSV_Employees[0].psobject.properties.name){
    $output_array += $HEADER
}

$output_array = $output_array | ForEach-Object {'''$($' + "LINE.$_"} 
$output_variable= $output_array-join ")', "
$output_variable= """(" + $output_array + ")')"""

foreach($LINE in $CSV_Employees){
   $output_variable
}
```

Output:

"('$($LINE.Id)', '$($LINE.FirstName)', '$($LINE.LastName)', '$($LINE.Salary)', '$($LINE.Department)', '$($LINE.Country)')"

"('$($LINE.Id)', '$($LINE.FirstName)', '$($LINE.LastName)', '$($LINE.Salary)', '$($LINE.Department)', '$($LINE.Country)')"

"('$($LINE.Id)', '$($LINE.FirstName)', '$($LINE.LastName)', '$($LINE.Salary)', '$($LINE.Department)', '$($LINE.Country)')"

"('$($LINE.Id)', '$($LINE.FirstName)', '$($LINE.LastName)', '$($LINE.Salary)', '$($LINE.Department)', '$($LINE.Country)')"

"('$($LINE.Id)', '$($LINE.FirstName)', '$($LINE.LastName)', '$($LINE.Salary)', '$($LINE.Department)', '$($LINE.Country)')"

"('$($LINE.Id)', '$($LINE.FirstName)', '$($LINE.LastName)', '$($LINE.Salary)', '$($LINE.Department)', '$($LINE.Country)')"

The problem that I am looking to solve is within the foreach loop at the end. It just prints the content of the variable that I am passing. I know that this is the usual behavior but is it possible to treat this variable like an actual piece of code?

The end goal is to create a SQL INSERT INTO statement out of a CSV file. This exact piece is the one that would create the VALUES section of the INSERT INTO statement with all rows of the data from the CSV file. This needs to work for different CSV files, so the column names can't be fixed.

I am using a sample data, which looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the end goal here? Can you share the first 5 lines of the CSV file, along with your desired output?

Comment: Please [edit your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73557415/edit) and add new details, comments are not well fit for code and data exchange :)

Comment: Note that only `"..."` strings (double-quoted aka _expandable strings_) perform string interpolation (expansion of variable values and expressions), not `'...'` strings (single-quoted aka _verbatim strings_). With `"..."` quoting, if the string value itself contains `"` chars., escape them as `\`"` or `""`, or use a double-quoted _here-string_.  See the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't "prepare" your statements, just expand the values as needed *when you actually get to them* in the second loop:

```
$CSV_Employees = Import-Csv "C:\Users\L_L\Desktop\Employees_v2.csv"

# No need for the loop here
$columnNames = @($CSV_Employees[0].psobject.Properties.Name)

$insertStatements = foreach($employee in $CSV_Employees){
    $values = $columnNames.ForEach({
        # fetch value from `$employee.$_`, escape single quotes
        "'{0}'" -f $employee.$_.Replace("'","''")
    })

    # Generate insert command string
    "INSERT INTO dbo.TableName ($($output_array -join ', ')) VALUES ($($values -join ', '))"
}
```

`$insertStatements` now contains all the generated SQL insert statements